# Rewrite / to /mypage.html without redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change the home page

```
http://www.example.com/
```

to show content from

```
http://www.example.com/mypage.html
```

.htaccess only methods please.

I don't want the page to redirect.  I need the homepage to show different content from the same website.  Literally switching the homepage to now show a category page instead.

---

Here is the current magento .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /furniture/living-room.html
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

My Website is http://www.onemegamarket.com/

Comment: `RewriteRule` doesn't redirect by default, it's an internal rewrite. Does `RewriteRule ^/?$ /mypage.html` not work?

Comment: no didnt make a different, i will add the full .htaccess to the original question now

Comment: You're stacking multiple rewrite rules. The last rule `.* index.php` is going to match. To break early on your homepage rule add the `[L]` (last) flag.

Comment: im not sure this is the default magento .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Add the `[L]` flag to your rewrite rule to avoid matching the catch-all as well.

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /furniture/living-room.html [L]
```

Comment: Plus1, the current home page is certainly showing furniture now. Maybe Daniel just needed to clear his browser cache.